# Devops with OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to build a new app by using a docker image from the book Devops With OpenShift
so as per the content from the book  page 19
the command is

```
oc new-app devopswithopenshift/welcome:latest --name=myapp
```

so the `devopswithopenshift/welcome:latest` needs to be firstly built and pushed to the docker hub.
I pulled the GIT code from https://github.com/devops-with-openshift/welcome
and ran the command `C:\Docker\welcome\foo>docker build -t welcome .`

Here is the response

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

When i looked into the Dockerfile

It has `FROM welcome/ops:latest`
so it is trying to pull `welcome/ops` which is not there in the registry can the authors help resolve this

Thanks
K.ThulsiDoss

Comment: The image `devopswithopenshift/welcome:latest` already [exists on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/devopswithopenshift/welcome). The command line you've shown (`oc new-app devopswithopenshift/welcome:latest --name=myapp`) runs successfully without any changes (although the referenced image seems to be over four years old, so I would probably not suggest actually working with it).

Comment: Thanks for the response .Here is what i did to get going so that users can benefit from the clarifications. 
1.My env is windows (client ) and open shift is on RHEL cluster .In my win env i have Git ,OC client installed & docker (win10 ) installed
2.Downloaded the book code into my git dir
3.The important thing is that i logged onto docker with my credentials on the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response .Here is what i did to get going so that users can benefit from the clarifications.
1.My env is windows (client ) and open shift is on RHEL cluster .In my win env i have Git ,OC client installed & docker (win10 ) installed
2.Downloaded the book code into my git dir
3.The important thing is that i logged onto docker with my credentials on the terminal
'''
e.g **docker login** --  --password  on the terminal where i had extracted the code.
'''
4.I then logged onto the OC cluster e.g
'''
oc login --token= --server=https://xyzopenshift.os.fyre.ibm.com:6443